# AngularJS + RequireJS + angular-ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to use angular-ui-grid with AngularJS and RequireJS. See plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5P2GAxIdPNbC5EvcKn4h).

My index31.html has grid and indexController.js defines the gridOptions object. indexController is injected when needed.

When browser loads indexController.js before index31.html, it works fine (i.e. grid is displayed) but when it is the other way round, I get error: `$scope.uiGrid is undefined.`

How do I specify (in $stateProvider config or elsewhere) to always load indexController.js before index31.html. Or, how do I make all controllers load before the html?

Comment: Your plunker link is not working

Comment: @Cyberdelphos thanks, i've updated it. adding here too .. http://plnkr.co/edit/5P2GAxIdPNbC5EvcKn4h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that you require the actual code of the controller asynchronously, i.e. with an inline `require`:

```
// app.js
define(function () {
    ...
    app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$injector', function ($scope, $injector) {
        // HERE!!!
        require(['indexController'], function (controller) {
            $injector.invoke(controller, this, { '$scope': $scope });
        });
    }]);
});
```

There is no guarantee for the order of loading with this pattern.

**What can you do:** Require the `'indexController'` at the top:

```
define(['indexController'], function (indexController) {
    ...
    app.controller('IndexController', indexController);
});
```

It even removes the (horrible IMO) usage of `$injector`!

(Sidenote: Doing this, the plunk complained about the `$scope.$apply()` in the last line of `indexController.js`; I commented it out, it really seems redundant.)

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/fsyljR8FEeZdvXB3SRJP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @Nikos. By doing this, I would need to load all my controllers before defining the angular application module. I'm trying to load controllers only when they are required, to avoid loading those controllers that may never be required by user (say, due to his level of authorization or some pages that he may never open)(I have a mid to large sized application, so limiting what gets downloaded also made sense). This is why I went with the approach of asynchronously loading controllers. Is there a different, better approach to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: See [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy) for lazy loading - it is my take on the problem there are also others.

Comment: If however you want to lazy-load controllers this way: (1) The `indexController` is outside the `ui-view` - it should probably be eager loaded anyway. (2) For *view* controllers, you can still lazy load them utilizing the `resolve` attribute of the state. So, in the `resolve`, you return a promise which gets resolved when `require` has fetched the controller.

Comment: Thanks! let me try these options too.